# JSON Map Fields and How to Query

Tags: json, pyspark

I am looking for a solution to a JSON formatted table.  Currently I need to return values in fields that are related to specific instances.  We are looking for a specific value in a mapped field and need to return the corresponding value from another field.  example below

```
`**case when field["1"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["1"]  
     when field["2"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["2"] 
     when field["3"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["3"] 
     when field["4"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["4"] 
     when field["5"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["5"] 
     when field["6"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["6"] 
     when field["7"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["7"] 
     when field["8"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["8"]  
     when field["9"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["9"] end as p_attribute**`
```

The value XXXXX can appear in any field["1"] through field["15"] and I need to return the corresponding attribute to the field["?"] from the corresponding attribute variable.

Looking for a similar function to the ARRAY function in SAS.

Prefer not to have to write the case statement for 100 variables when I'm not sure where the value XXXXX will appear and it could potentially go further than field["15"]

Any assistance is appreciated.

See above example
`**case when field["1"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["1"]   when field["2"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["2"]  when field["3"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["3"]  when field["4"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["4"]  when field["5"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["5"]  when field["6"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["6"]  when field["7"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["7"]  when field["8"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["8"]   when field["9"] = "XXXXX" then attribute["9"] end as p_attribute**`

Answer (score 0):

```html
data = {
    "field": {
        "1": "XXXXX",
        "2": "YYYYY",
        "3": "ZZZZZ"
    },
    "attribute": {
        "1": "Attribute1",
        "2": "Attribute2",
        "3": "Attribute3"
    }
}

search_value = "XXXXX"

field_to_attribute = {
    key: data["attribute"][key]
    for key, value in data["field"].items()
    if value == search_value
}

print(field_to_attribute)
```

In Python

You can use dictionary search for this using a loop

if i get any sample of your json format i can help more